# erreur with pg module: undefined Promise

Tags: node.js, pg

Im begginer with node.js.
i work with old project and i have problem with pg module.
PS: the pg was delete and when and re-install.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt4GQ.png)

Comment: You must be using an ancient version of Node.js, prior to 0.12.x, where was no support for type `Promise`, hence the problem. If you need to support promises correctly with any version of Node.js, check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your version of node ? If you use node v6 all should work correct.
Try to install this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise) and do next

```
var promise = require('promise');
var pg = require('pg');

var pool = new pg.Pool({
    // your connection settings
    Promise: promise
});
```

It should work.